# Listen to browser width / height changes with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, height, width

I have some divs that are set with position absolute (CSS) when the page is ready, and are positioned relative to another fixed div, which works fine. However, before the page is loaded and everything is set, if the page is resized, those absolute divs don't follow the changes, moving to other places, which I think they are given values relative to top and left of the screen.

The position of the relative div I use as starting point to position the absolute ones may change position as well, relative to the ones above it.

Is there any way to listen the changes in the browser's width / height in order to make those divs stay placed in the right position?

Comment: There are ways to listen to changes using JavaScript, buit doesn't "position: fixed" already solve your problem?

Comment: No, it doesn't, because "position: fixed" follows the scroll of the browser, loosing the position relative to another div that I need.

Comment: I think this might be possible without javascript if only we knew what it is actually that you want. I know an answer is accepted but a pure css answer for this question will help out others as well.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can show sample HTML for what you want to achieve. From your current question it is unclear just as r-dub mentioned.

Comment: I think you don't really need that, the only thing you need to know is that there's a relative node in the markup and an absolute node that would change his position in the screen depending on the relative node position. Don't have any markup now, this question was posted about a year ago.

Comment: but its not relatives divs, you say they are fixed divs. and it might change its position relative to the ones above it. But yeah 1 year. so no need to dig this.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

First you want to start with binding the window resize event to a function of your choosing.

```
$(window).on("resize", methodToFixLayout);
```

Now you can determine the new heights and widths and make adjustments to the page from there.

```
function methodToFixLayout( e ) {
    var winHeight = $(window).height();
    var winWidth = $(window).width();
    //adjust elements css etc.....
    //$("#someDiv").css('someProperty',someValue based on winHeight and winWidth);
}
```

Without more specifics on your layout it's hard to tell what changes you'll need exactly but this should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to do the calculations with the resize event, in some very small lines of code, much less than I expected!

Comment: @yoda if you're going to ask a question and get good answers and respond with, "I found a better way", why not post your better way, it's kinda how these sites work ;)

Comment: @Nik I used this answer, just adapted it to match my conditions, so the answer to the problem is the one pointed as such.

Comment: I think you should update `bind` to `on` on is what we use on this time

Answer (score 4):

It may not be necessary to use JavaScript if you only need to position your element(s) relative to another element instead of the overall document. You can use "position:relative":

```
<div id="myContainer" style="position:relative">

    <div id="myElement" style="position:absolute;left:100px;"></div>

</div>
```

Because myContainer has `position:relative`, myElement will be positioned absolutely but *relative* to myContainer instead of relative to the overall document. Armed with this, you can construct quite elaborate, but robust positions that will be browser-size-agnostic.

Comment: thanks for pointing it, I forgot to say that the position of the element wich i use as "anchor" to the absolute has his position changed when the divs above change their height, after the page is loaded. Also, the page itself is centered in the screen.

Answer (score 2):

There is also this plugin from jqui website.

http://www.jqui.net/jquery-projects/jquery-mutate-official/

here is demo: http://www.jqui.net/demo/mutate/

hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the link, sure will be helpful in a near future :)