# Can jquery detect changes in width of a table column

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table that has multiples columns, and all columns have headers. When data is loaded into the table via ajax, sometimes the column width changes. How can I detect changes to the widths of any of the columns? Can it be done with jquery?

Comment: You mean something like a listener for computed css width's change event?

Comment: @Fabrício Matté Yeah, like a listener for when the width changes.

Comment: This is similar to this, I have added my solution here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655343/listen-to-browser-width-height-changes-with-jquery or go to the actual website... http://www.jqui.net/jquery-projects/jquery-mutate-official/

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately there is no solid and reliable method for detecting changes in the dimensions of an element. As an alternative, perhaps you could add a bit of code to the ajax that records the starting (perhaps with `beforeSend`) and ending width (from within `success`). When it differs, fire off a custom event using `.trigger()`. Subscribe to that event from anywhere in your app to respond to a change in width.