# Jquery issue not to refresh browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I write the following code so that if the browser width increases or decreases, jquery should add or remove the container class, but that needs to refresh the browser which I don't want, Is there any alternative?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
if($(window).width() > 1183)
{
$('.intro > ul').removeClass('container');
}
else if ($(window).width() <= 1183)
{
$('.intro > ul').addClass('container');
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: Where is your event listener? Add this to your code... document ready... then $(window).on('resize', function(){ your code to add or remove class});

Comment: Why not just use a CSS media query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen to the resize event of the window without refreshing

```
$(window).on("resize", function(){
   //Your code for adding/removing class
});
```

[Listen to browser width / height changes with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655343/listen-to-browser-width-height-changes-with-jquery)